# Make volume and brightness sliders stay open on macbook pro touch bar

Tags: touch-bar

I have already changed the setting in Keyboard Settings for the Touch Bar shows to Expanded Control Strip and I have volume and brightness sliders loaded onto the expanded control strip.

However, I still have to press the button before I slide. Can I make the sliders stay open?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve that without any third app.

- [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) is probably the most famous one, and let you customize your TouchBar as you like. You can try it for free for 45 days to see if it suits you.

You can see on the picture below an exemple, with the brightness slider as you want :

[image: BTT]

- [My TouchBar My rules](https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR) is a BetterTouchTool applike but free, however it's not very user friendly...

On the default preset below, you have both the brightness and volume sliders as you want :

[image: MTMR]